# In spring using websockets getting this error,uncaught type error: onrecieve is not a function(..) stomp.js

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am getting this error:

> uncaught type error: onrecieve is not a function(..) stomp.js

Can anyone help me and provide me complete setting using stockjs, stomp and jars?

My file:home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Reload..</title>




<%--  <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url  value="/static/scripts/jquery.js"/>'></script>  --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/static/scripts/sockjs-  0.3.4.js"/>'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/static/scripts/stomp.js"/>'></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   var stompClient=null;

  var onDebug = function(m) {
    console.log('DEBUG', m);
  };

  var connect=function(){
  var socket = new SockJS("/testwebsockets/portfolio");
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
   stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    console.log('Connecteds: ' + frame);
 stompClient.debug = onDebug;
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/portfolio",{},function(msgput){
    console.log("msg:"+msgput.body);
  });
},function(error){
  alert(error);
});
};





  var sendMessage=function(){
  stompClient.debug = onDebug;
  stompClient.send("/app/portfolio",   {},JSON.stringify({from:'kk',text:'hello'}));
  };



 </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div>
            <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>


        <br />
        <div id="conversationDiv">

            <button id="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage();">Send</button>

        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Thats the jsp file using Javascript code to connect to websockets. It does connect but on receiving it back from controller getting this error:

> uncaught type error: onrecieve is not a function(..) stomp.js
>
> Opening Web Socket...
>   stomp.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:130 Web Socket Opened...
>   stomp.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:130 >>> CONNECT
>   accept-version:1.1,1.0
>   heart-beat:10000,10000
>
> <<< CONNECTED
>   version:1.1
>   heart-beat:0,0
>
> connected to server undefined
>   (index):34 Connecteds: CONNECTED
>   heart-beat:0,0
>   version:1.1
>
> DEBUG >>> SUBSCRIBE
>   id:sub-0
>   destination:/topic/portfolio
>
> DEBUG >>> SEND
>   destination:/app/portfolio
>   content-length:28
>
> {"from":"kk","text":"hello"}
>
> DEBUG <<< MESSAGE
>   destination:/topic/portfolio
>   content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   subscription:sub-0
>   message-id:h8_q6giw-0
>   content-length:48
>
> {"from":"kk","text":"hello","timeStamp":"08:26"}
>
> stomp.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:288 Uncaught TypeError:   onreceive is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @   stomp.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:288REventTarget.dispatchEvent @
>   sockjs-0.3.4.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:84SockJS._dispatchMessage @
>    sockjs-0.3.4.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:1025SockJS._didMessage @
>    sockjs-0.3.4.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:1083that.ws.onmessage @
>    sockjs-0.3.4.js;jsessionid=45714C4BB09BD6111D49A41D92FBBAC0:1215

Comment: well i m using all code  like in this blog http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from an errant extra argument that you pass to the `subscribe` method.

```
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/portfolio",{},function(msgput){
    console.log("msg:"+msgput.body);
});
```

should become:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/portfolio",function(msgput){
    console.log("msg:"+msgput.body);
});
```

Comment: I'm glad it is working. In the future, make sure to post your relevant code with your question. Now you see how helpful it can be to us in order to help you!

Comment: can i add u at my skype?