# STOMP Protocol with SockJS Middleware Example for Redux + React Native

Tags: react-native, websocket, redux, middleware, stomp

## Context

I am currently building a React Native app that uses web sockets to provide some real-time functionality. I have redux implemented and working and I am now trying to create the middleware that will maintain the web socket connection. While I am familiar with React Native and Redux, Socket connections are new to me.
The Server to which the app is connecting to is built with Spring - It makes use of SockJS and uses the STOMP protocol.

## Problem

I am unsure of the correct way to implement the middleware with STOMP. While I have come across many examples of initiating Socket.io connections and SockJ, I have been unable to find any that utilise STOMP that work. I am looking for an example or library that may be able to help me.

## What I've Tried

While researching I have come across, and attempted to use the following example just to get things up and running:

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'
import Stomp from 'stomp'

var stompClient = null;

const ws_url = 'MYURL'
const token = 'MYTOKEN'

export const setupSocket = (dispatch) => {
 var socket = new SockJS(ws_url+token);
 stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  
 stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('MY TOPIC', function(messageOutput) {
       console.log(messageOutput);
    });
    }
 );
}
```

This presented me with an error stating that 'stomp.default.over' is not a function (I looked at [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063968/in-spring-using-websockets-getting-this-error-uncaught-type-error-onrecieve-is) but it is not applicable)

I have been able to successfully create a connection with sockJS without STOMP.

## Extra Details

- I am not looking for a component based solution as middleware seems
  to be the best practise (otherwise something like
  [react-stomp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stomp) would be
  perfect!).
- A solution utilising *thunk* would be great as I already
  am using it elsewhere in the application.
- Changing to another protocol is not possible.

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: do you have a solution to this?